# Download images using core data in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios7, download

I have requirement where I need to download the images from web services at loading time to core data.. can tell me the best way to download the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSMutableArray *al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData2 options:0 error:nil];


        for (NSDictionary *diction in al)
        {
            NSString *geting =[diction valueForKey:@"dealimage"];

            getdata = [NSData dataFromBase64String:geting ];

            dataimages=[UIImage imageWithData:getdata];

           [imagesarray addObject:dataimages];
        }
```

And then You flow this link how to stored Array Data to CoreData

https://coderwall.com/p/mx_wmq